# Error: No module named 'PyQt5.sip' - When installing eric6-19.03

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-3.6, raspberry-pi3

I have noticed a number of similar questions on stackoverflow, but none that really helped me with my current challenge. I have been attempting to install eric6 on my Raspberry Pi setup. And then I encountered the following messages:

```
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.6.8
PyQt5 could not be detected.
Error: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'

Shall 'PyQt5' be installed using pip? (Y/n) Y
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (5.12)
Sorry, please install PyQt5.
Error: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

And when I attempt to use the pip list to look at what has been installed (as I previously already managed to make and install the PyQt5 from source code):

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.0.3 
PyQt5      5.12   
setuptools 40.6.2 
sip        4.19.14
```

So, how do I overcome the issue that I am currently facing? By the way, I am using the following command when attempting to install eric6:

```
python3 install.py
```

Thought you might need to know that if it helps.

Comment: My answer below assumes you're using Raspbian, you're on Stretch, and that you installed Python 3.6 yourself (but I don't know how). These things would have been helpful in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 isn't available in any Raspbian distribution, so I assume you installed this yourself. You can't install an out-of-distribution Python version and expect distribution Python packages to work. You have PyQt5 installed, yes, but it's the version of PyQt built for Python 3.5 (I'm assuming you're on Raspbian Stretch).

Sometimes you can install Python libraries with pip, and in theory that could work to install the correct version of PyQt for your version of Python, but PyQt only provides wheels for x86 [on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files), not for Arm, so PyQt is not pip installable on the Pi. The only way to get PyQt on Raspberry Pi is via apt, where your choices are Jessie (old stable - with Python 3.4), Stretch (current stable - with Python 3.5), and Buster (unstable/testing - with Python 3.7). If there's a need for Python >3.5, your best bet is to try upgrading to Buster, but bear in mind it's not ready for release yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Yes, you are right that I am on Stretch, upgraded to the latest Debian as well. And yeap, I understand that some of the things that I am currently doing are considered experimental. So it's probably true that some of the things that I'm trying to do just ain't going to work normally. But it was worth trying. Never try, never know.